# Grid row hiding child other elements

Tags: c#, wpf

I have the following simple WPF code where my expectation is to create a 2 rows 3 columns grid with grid splitters on the columns. But the grid splitters are visible and working fine as long as I don't split the rows in the grid.

Below is the sample code:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="100" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="30"  />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1"
                  Grid.RowSpan="2"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
          VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
          Background="LightGray" 
          ShowsPreview="true"
          Width="3" />
    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="2"
                  Grid.RowSpan="2"
          HorizontalAlignment="Left" 
          VerticalAlignment="Stretch"
          Background="LightGray" 
          ShowsPreview="true"
          Width="3"/>
    <!--Button x:Name="button" Grid.Row="1" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Height="27" Grid.Column="1" Margin="19,42,0,0" /-->
</Grid>
```

I gave the Grid.RowSpan = 2 thinking that it would make the grid splitter span over the two rows that I have. However, when I run this code, I am getting this.

[image]
The second row is over lapping the the grid splitters and they are not visible. The blue line represents the outline. I just want the vertical grid splitters to span over the entire window. What am I doing wrong here? I even declared the grid splitters at the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the only problem with multiple rows in your sample is that they don't take full height of the Grid.

1st row has `30` height, 2nd has a height depending on content (`Auto`). without any content it will be `0`. blue lines on screenshot *don't show the real outline*. to fix the layout make 2nd row fill the height: `Height="*"`

```
<Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <RowDefinition Height="30"  />
    <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
</Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

Comment: Thank you. Now I know why after uncommenting the button tag, the splitter was showing up until where button was